# how to make cmd.exe inherit user variable instead of system variable

Tags: windows, path

My cmd.exe when started always inherit SYSTEM settings of PATH which could not be changed due to GROUP POLICY set by firm.

[Related: Windows XP Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/321029/windows-xp-environment-variables)
but my cmd.exe 's PATH is not a combination of USER and SYSTEM it is SYSTEM only, is this also specified by the GROUP POLICY ?

how to make it inherit from my USER version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know, this configuration is specified in Group Policy, users without admin access can really do nothing about it.